# performance in class template

Tags: c++, performance, templates

I have a class template as below

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    A(T t) : m_t(move(t)) {}
    operator T const&() const { return m_t; }        

private:
    T m_t;
};
```

When `T` is `int`

(1) Does the `move` in the constructor has performance drop comparing with no move?

(2) Does the `operator T const&()` has performance drop comparing with `operator T&()`?

Comment: You probably mean `operator T()` for (2).

Answer (score 0):

1. Copying and moving and int is the same because an int lives in the stack and has no remote parts.

Consider:

```
struct A {
   int A;
};

struct B {
   std::string str;
};
```

For A, copying and moving is the same (copy the int, which is embedded). For B, copying is allocating memory (usually) for a string. But moving would be just copying the pointer that points to the heap-allocated memory from the string, an O(1) operation, and maybe the size of the string. A string has remote parts, so when you move only the pointer is copied.

2. Compilers are very good at optimizing, I am sure it will generate the same code for an int, since an int is not polymorphic or derivable (a class).

Comment: `move(int i)` with get a new copy of `i` and then assign the new copy to `m_t`? so there is one more copy?

Comment: in order to understand what move is, you have to know that move is only a different thing from copy when an object has remotely allocated parts. In the case of an int, a move and a copy is the same.